# splitting the data based on condition in Apache camel routing

Tags: xml, routes, apache-camel

Problem Statement: I have XML file as follows:

```
<Orders>
    <Order>
        <OrderNo>1234</OrderNo>
        <EnterpriseCode>1</EnterpriseCode>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <OrderNo>1234</OrderNo>
        <EnterpriseCode>2</EnterpriseCode>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <OrderNo>1234</OrderNo>
        <EnterpriseCode>1</EnterpriseCode>
    </Order>
</Orders>
```

**I want to split the data based on the EnterpriseCode. Like if EnterpriseCode="1" then**

```
<Order>
    <OrderNo>1234</OrderNo>
    <EnterpriseCode>1</EnterpriseCode>
</Order>
<Order>
    <OrderNo>1234</OrderNo>
    <EnterpriseCode>1</EnterpriseCode>
</Order>
```

The above result push to one file f1.

**if EnterpriseCode="2" then**

```
<Order>
    <OrderNo>1234</OrderNo>
    <EnterpriseCode>2</EnterpriseCode>
</Order>
```

push to another file f2

**I want Apache camel route code to resolve this in XML format.
I tried with the following:**

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"> 
    <route id="com.trainingaccount11.Route1" autoStartup="false"> 
        <from uri="b2bmbFileSystem:com.trainingaccount11/second-input"/>
        <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" charset="UTF-8"/>
        <convertBodyTo type="org.w3c.dom.Document" charset="UTF-8"/>     
        <split>
            <xpath>//Order/EnterpriseCode[text()='1']</xpath>
            <setBody>
                <xpath>//Order</xpath>
            </setBody>
            <log message="${body}"/>
            <to uri="b2bmbFileSystem:com.trainingaccount11/logs5" />
        </split>
    </route> 
</routes>
```

**But I am not getting the Expected result.**

**I am expecting following output as follows from this code:**

```
<Order>
    <OrderNo>1234</OrderNo>
    <EnterpriseCode>1</EnterpriseCode>
</Order>
<Order>
    <OrderNo>1234</OrderNo>
    <EnterpriseCode>1</EnterpriseCode>
</Order>
```

please suggest me the solution

Comment: What result do you get now?

Comment: <EnterpriseCode>1</EnterpriseCode>  only this I am getting but I am expecting <Order>
    <OrderNo>1234</OrderNo>
    <EnterpriseCode>1</EnterpriseCode>
</Order>
<Order>
    <OrderNo>1234</OrderNo>
    <EnterpriseCode>1</EnterpriseCode>
</Order>

Comment: Not sure why you have that `<setBody>` inside the splitter. But use an xpath evaluator tool and try to find the xpath expression that returns the entity you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the `<EnterpriseCode>` element as result because your XPath `//Order/EnterpriseCode[text()='1']`is selecting it.

If you want the XPath to return the `Order` element, it must look like this. Notice that the base xpath determines the result selection whereas the query part in `[...]` defines conditions that are "deeper" that the selected element.

```
<xpath>/Orders/Order[EnterpriseCode='1']</xpath>
```

However, in your example this xpath produces two result "rows". Therefore you probably get them as two messages from the splitter. Because in one message the result would be invalid XML (two `Order` elements would need an enclosing root element).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. as you said, from the above solution you given , it produces the result as expected. But when <xpath>/Orders/Order[EnterpriseCode='1']</xpath> is true it should produce the 2 rows. I am getting one row only. <Order>
    <OrderNo>1234</OrderNo>
    <EnterpriseCode>1</EnterpriseCode>
</Order>

Comment: but I need 2 rows <Order>
    <OrderNo>1234</OrderNo>
    <EnterpriseCode>1</EnterpriseCode>
</Order>
<Order>
    <OrderNo>1234</OrderNo>
    <EnterpriseCode>1</EnterpriseCode>
</Order> is there any way to create root element for these orders and put it in file in camel

Comment: If you want to split all orders and re-collect those with the same `EnterpriseCode` you should take a look at the [combined splitter-aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/composed-message-processor.html). This is kind of a fork/join component that does exactly that. It is in fact a splitter with an integrated aggregator.